# Auth0 - Authenticating with RS256 using JWT on Owin with bearer-accessToken

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, auth0

While implementing Auth0 Authentication/Authorization with a normal embedded login, I am able to authenticate the user and gets back the valid **accessToken/idToken**.

- Initialization

  ```
  webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: 'xxx.auth0.com',
      clientID: 'myclientid',
      responseType: 'token id_token'
  });
  ```
- Successfully getting token.

  ```
  webAuth.client.login({
      realm: _Connection,
      username: 'aaa@b.com',
      password: 'password',
      audience: 'https://xxx.auth0.com/api/v2/',
      scope: 'openid profile email'
  }, function (err, args) {
      if (!err) 
        {
         webAuth.client.userInfo(token, function (args, authUserData) {
          var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
          ***Setting bearer token to Global level.**
          ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
           headers: ({ "Authorization": "Bearer " + token })
          };
          myAPICall(args.email).then({}).fail({});
         });
      }
  });
  ```
- Server code which is validating RS256 signed JWT with OWIN.

  ```
  private void ConfigureAuthZero(IAppBuilder app)
  {
      var issuer = $"https://{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0:Domain"]}/";
      var audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0:ClientID"];
      var apiIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0:ApiIdentifier"];
      app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      string certificatePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/mycertificate.cer");
      var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath);
      app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
          new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
          {
              AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
              TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
              {
                  ValidAudience = audience,
                  ValidIssuer = issuer,
                  IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) => new X509SecurityKey(certificate)
              }
          });
  }
  ```

**My Problem**:

The above server code won't authorize the user.
But if I set `ValidAudience = "https://xxx.auth0.com/api/v2/"` i.e to Auth0 API Identifier, then the API method successfully authorizes (status 200) the user.

But this time it won't give **ClaimsIdentity.Claims** with **ClaimTypes.Email**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My mistakes:**

1. I should pass **ApiIdentifier** to **ValidAudience** value.
2. As I was passing **accessToken** while authorizing the user, by the
   time the accessToken claims doesn't contain the ClaimTypes.Email, so
   I need to set the rules in Auth0 as:[How to set the rules in Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/current).
   Which later I can check in my server api logic as(below code) to
   validate the user.
   `(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "you-have-set-this-rule-in-auth0")?.Value;`

Just to Add-on, The [Link](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/validating-rs256-signed-jwt-certificate/) worth reading while implementing the Auth0.
Auth0 has provided a nice nuget package **Auth0.OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver** which has a nice use in the above provided link.